# Can i do logical Query inside Blob column field in cassandra Query?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1

Can i do logical Query inside Blob column field in cassandra Query ?

like i have a file inside Blob field called purchase amount : 500$ i want to do search and fetch results purchase amount which is greater than 500$.

is there way i can do this logical search inside my blob.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible out of box. For Cassandra, `blob` type is just a set of bytes.  You can potentially use [user-defined functions](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/functions.html) to extract necessary data, but it could be tricky from performance standpoint.

P.S. I feel that Cassandra may not be correct product for you if you need to search by substring or something like this.  In Cassandra you need to model your data based on queries, and then select column types, etc.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. can you please suggest what Data base would be best for this ? im going to use this for Audit purpose. when doing audit they may any type of auditing. so my db should be able to provide all type of auditing. 

thanks in advance

Comment: It’s a broad question. It’s all depends on your requirements. It includes how do you want to search, what amount of data, response time, etc?